# Building TIC fails (ncurses5.9) for CLFS 3.0.0 SYSTEMD

Tags: linux, ncurses, clfs

Recently I decided to retry building a CLFS machine http://www.clfs.org and am at step 5.5 of 3.0.0 SYSTEMD. We are told to run `make -C include` and then `make -C progs tic`. I am failing at the last command. Am I missing any packages, or am I doing something wrong?

I am using ArchLinux as my CLFS host in VMWare which is running on Windows 10.

Here is the page I am looking at for the commands: http://clfs.org/files/BOOK/3.0.0/SYSTEMD/view/x86_64/cross-tools/ncurses.html

Here is the output from the console when I run that last command:

```
    In file included from ../ncurses/curses.priv.h:283:0,
    from ../ncurses/lib_gen.c:19:_33528.c:835:15: error: expected ')' before 'int'
    ../include/curses.h:1594:56: note: in definition of macro 'mouse_trafo'
    #define mouse_trafo(y,x,to_screen) wmouse_trafo(stdscr,y,x,to_screen)
                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pointing to the `y` symbol,

- which could be (mis)defined in some header file on your system.
- aside from stray #define's, the only interesting thing about the line is that the prototype for `wmouse_trafo` uses `bool`, which the configure script should have (given the compiler version used for CLFS) equated to a c99 `_Bool` (which should not be a problem).

You can see what the compiler sees by doing

```
make -C ncurses lib_gen.i
```

and looking for `wmouse_trafo` in `ncurses/lib_gen.i`.

For example, I see it mentioned twice:

```
extern _Bool wmouse_trafo (const WINDOW*, int*, int*, _Bool);
extern _Bool mouse_trafo (int*, int*, _Bool);
```

and

```
 _Bool (mouse_trafo) (int * a1, int * a2, _Bool z)
{
 ; return wmouse_trafo(stdscr,a1,a2,z);
}
```

The stray semicolon is not a problem, but if there were some problem with the cross-compiler it might make the `_Bool` missing.

The instructions for CLFS 3.0 use [gcc 4.8.3](http://clfs.org/files/BOOK/3.0.0/SYSTEMD/view/x86_64/cross-tools/gcc-final.html) (versions of all of the parts do matter).  However, the error message cited here looks like a recent report due to gcc 5 — which is addressed in [ncurses 6.0](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html)

Comment: In lib_gen.i I found `wmouse_trafo (const WINDOW*, int*, int*,` `wmouse_trafo(stdscr,int * a1,int * a2,` and `;return wmouse_trafo(stdscr,a1,a2,z);`

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy for the last week or so, I finally decided to scrap the project and restart. I will have to either wait for the project to update or find a way to use the old version